# Como puedo poner una fuente especifica a un input text?

Tags: html

Quisiera que me digan el **codigo entero** de una página web vacia en HTML que solo contenga un elemento tipo input text donde se pueda escribir en una fuente especifica como **Comic Sans MS**

Yo probe así pero no me funciono:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" font-family="helvetica">
</body>
</html>
```

***Muchas gracias.***

Comment: Puedes descargar o usar las fuentes gratuitas de google([aqui](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Coming+Soon?selection.family=Open%20Sans)) Solo es que añadas el <link> para añadir la letra y definas en css que campos lo tomaran. Te adjunto un ejemplo sencillo [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/AlejoFlorez0/pen/WMVpNz?editors=1100)

Comment: Sugerencia: leer más sobre cómo funciona CSS. Te han dado varias sugerencias pero parece que hay vacíos en conceptos básicos que impiden que uses de forma eficiente las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar CSS

HTML

```
<body>
  <input type="text" class="input1">
</body>
```

CSS

```
.input1 { 
   font-size: 24px; 
   font-family: monospace; //aqui estableces el tipo de fuente
}
```

Comment: El CSS lo pongo en head o en body?

Comment: en donde tu quieras, incluso en el input le puedes poner la propiedad Style="  ....codigo css " y su codigo css

Answer (score 0):

Lo que has hecho es poner `font-family` como un atributo HTML, lo cual no es correcto. Para modificar la fuente de un elemento html, necesitas utilizar `CSS`.

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  input {
   font-family: helvetica;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Cualquier duda, deja un comentario.

Comment: Como puedo poner mas fuentes como Comic Sans MS?

Comment: Si es una fuente externa, es un procedimiento diferente. Si no valdría con poner el nombre de ella. Luego actualizo la pregunta